Unable to run sonarqube scan due to java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation
Below is jdk 17 having class version 61 as set in the Path:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin>java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Property settings:
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.separator = \
    java.class.path =
    java.class.version = 61.0
    java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
    java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\U12207~1\AppData\Local\Temp\30\
    java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
        C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin
        C:\Windows\system32
        C:\Windows
        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin"
        D:\Git-Runners\_work\_tool\Python\3.12.3\x64\Scripts\
        D:\Git-Runners\USDF11V1566-s6\_work\_tool\Python\3.12.3\x64\
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin
        C:\Program Files\OpenLogic\jre-17.0.9.9-hotspot\bin
        C:\Python312\Scripts\
        C:\Python312\
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin
        C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
        D:\Git-Runners\s3\_work\_tool\Python\3.11.4\x64\Scripts\
        D:\Git-Runners\s3\_work\_tool\Python\3.11.4\x64\
        C:\Python311\Scripts\
        C:\Python311\
        C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\
        C:\Program Files\Python310\
        C:\FileNet\IDM
        C:\FileNet\Shared
        C:\Program Files\docker
        C:\Windows\system32
        C:\Windows
        C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
        C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
        C:\Program Files\dotnet\
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer
        C:\FileNet\FNSW\CLIENT\BIN
        C:\FileNet\FNSW\CLIENT\SHOBJ
        C:\Program Files\Git LFS
        D:\Jenkins\jre\bin
        C:\Users\automated-build\AppData\Roaming\npm
        C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
        C:\Program Files\Perforce\
        C:\Users\u1251433_app\Downloads\terraform_1.3.6_windows_amd641\
        D:\Jenkins\gradle-8.0.2\bin
        C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
        C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
        C:\PHP7
        C:\Program Files\nodejs
        C:\Program Files\Git\bin
        C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
        C:\Program Files\nodejs
        D:\Jenkins\tools\maven\bin
        C:\Program Files\ICW\bin
        C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\
        D:\Tools\Snyk
        D:\Jenkins\tools\terraform
        C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.16\bin
        C:\Program Files\Git\bin
        C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet-core-uninstall\
        C:\Program Files\nodejs\
        C:\Users\svc-areheal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
        .    
        .
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 17.0.11+7-LTS-207
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 17
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = https://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 17.0.11
    java.version.date = 2024-04-16
    java.vm.compressedOopsMode = Zero based
    java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 17
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 17.0.11+7-LTS-207
    jdk.debug = release
    line.separator = \r \n
    native.encoding = Cp1252
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Windows Server 2019
    os.version = 10.0
    path.separator = ;
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level =
    sun.stderr.encoding = cp437
    sun.stdout.encoding = cp437
    user.country = US
    user.dir = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
    user.home = C:\Users\u1220753_app
    user.language = en
    user.name = U1220753_app
    user.script =
    user.variant =

java version "17.0.11" 2024-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin>set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin";%PATH%;.;

Below is my sonarqube command to perform the scan:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin>D:\sonarscanner\scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat --define sonar.host.url="http://sonar-rm.mybank.com:9000/" --define sonar.login="***" --define sonar.projectKey="my_service" --define sonar.projectName="mybank/my-service" -Dsonar.java.binaries="D:\Git-Runners\_work\Velocity_StartStop\StartStop\service\src"
INFO: Scanner configuration file: NONE
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.6.1.2450
INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Windows Server 2019 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\u7899221_app\.sonar\cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: NONE
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 10.4.1.88267
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.566s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/60M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.DefaultBatchFactory.createBatch(DefaultBatchFactory.java:32)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

I used github's setup java workflow to setup java 1.8, 11 and version 17 but everytime i get the error reported above.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin>echo %PATH%
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin";D:\Git-Runners\s6\_work\_tool\Python\3.12.3\x64\Scripts\;D:\Git-Runners\s6\_work\_tool\Python\3.12.3\x64\;D:\Git-Runners\s3\_work\_tool\Python\3.11.4\x64\Scripts\;D:\Git-Runners\s3\_work\_tool\Python\3.11.4\x64\;;.;

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\

Upon inputs from user g00se i used jdk 11 for sonarqube and jdk 1.8 for compatibility using -Dsonar.java.jdkHome with source code being scanned. Output below:
D:\Git-Runners\s7\_work\_tool\Java_Adopt_jdk\11.0.23-9\x64\bin>D:\sonarscanner\scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat --define sonar.host.url="http://sonar-rm.mybank.com:9000/" --define sonar.login="***" --define sonar.projectKey="my_service" --define sonar.projectName="mybank/my-service" -Dsonar.java.jdkHome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8" -Dsonar.java.binaries="D:\Git-Runners\s1\_work\StartStop\StartStop\my-service\src"
INFO: Scanner configuration file: NONE
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.6.1.2450
INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Windows Server 2019 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\user12_app\.sonar\cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: NONE
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 10.4.1.88267
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.536s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/54M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/EnvironmentInformation has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:82)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.DefaultBatchFactory.createBatch(DefaultBatchFactory.java:32)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

D:\Git-Runners\s7\_work\_tool\Java_Adopt_jdk\11.0.23-9\x64\bin>

Can you please suggest how can i get sonarqube scanning to work?

Your Sonarqube is Java version 11. I don't know this software, but since the rest of your classes are 17, you probably need SQ >= 17. btw java.library.path looks weird. In fact it looks like PATH

@g00se I used github workflow https://github.com/actions/setup-java to setup version 11 distribution: 'Adopt' but it still fails with the same error.

That's what I just said ;) And that was your error afaics (I don't know this software). You should have set up >= 17

In my original post i have mention setting up jdk version 17 which is >= 17 yet i get the same error message @g00se.

OK, I missed that you tried with 17. I'll take a quick look at their script

btw, please post the output of echo %PATH% and echo %JAVA_HOME% The answer probably lies here

@g00se i updated the original post with the output of echo %PATH% and echo %JAVA_HOME%

You need to study the link I posted carefully

i read and specified java version 1.8 which is that of the source code being scanned using -Dsonar.java.jdkHome=<pathtojdk> but still the same error @g00se

@g00se Downloading the latest version of sonarqube scanner resolved the issue with the very command I was trying
